# How to show image in Blazor view

Tags: blazor

I am trying show images in a Blazor view, but it's not working and shows only an image icon:

```
<img src="~/Images/watch.jpg" asp-append-version="true" width="300px" />
```

Here my image resides in this path `wwwroot/Images/watch.jpg`

Answer (score 37):

You are probably running into this bug: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1216 and need to remove the ~ to make it work, or wait for the 0.6 release.

Comment: This worked for me, but what this solution underscores is pretty interesting and cool in my opinion. Basically, it highlights the whole purpose of blazor development feeling a bit more like C# and less like Web, giving you the ability to reference items in the project by simple folder directory navigation without having to think about how the user's browser needs to access the resource. Pretty cool. #nativeDev

Comment: Still had to remove the pig tail to make it work.

Comment: As at the date of this comment this is still the answer.

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
 <img src="/Images/watch.jpg" asp-append-version="true" width="300px" />
```

Answer (score 12):

Create a folder images under **wwwroot** then access it like **src="images/MyLogo.png"**

Answer (score 9):

Try this
`<img src="Images/watch.jpg" width="300px" />`
Just remove ~/ and it works.

Comment: This answer was already given a long time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136195/1879699

Comment: <img src="Images/watch.jpg" width="300px" /> work because it is place at wwwroot folder which is already registered

Answer (score 4):

In Blazor, it appears that you don't require a relative path or even the wwwroot part.
If your image is in wwwroot/images something like the following will work, (where class is a css that sets your image height)

img class="my_logo-img" src="/images/myLogoImage.png"

Answer (score 2):

Mine works when adding this: `<base href="~/" />` on your razor. This is already been placed to _Host.cshtml but you need to repeat adding it individually on your component pages.

Answer (score 1):

I have found for everything in blazor '../Images' is what you need.

If you do anything with images / css in Blazor, you might like this project called BlazorStyled by Chanan:

https://github.com/chanan/BlazorStyled

I recently built a sample project and tutorial with it called Blazor Image Gallery, that also uses my Nuget package DataJuggler.Blazor.FileUpload.

Here is one of the components called an ImageButton:

```
@using BlazorStyled

<Styled @bind-Classname="@ImageStyle">
    background-image: url('@ImageUrl'); 
    width: @WidthPixels;
    height: @HeightPixels;
    transform: scale(@Scale);
    transform-origin: left;   
    border: 2px solid black;
    z-index: @ZIndex;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: @ColumnLeftPixels;
    top: @RowTopPixels;
    display: inline-block;
</Styled>

<button class="@ImageStyle" @onclick="Button_Clicked"></button>
```

My ImageUrl property comes from my SQL Images table after a user uploads a file:

ImageUrl = '../Images/Gallery/Christina/Image1.08b2bb51-5.png'

Then in the usage I iterate my list of images for the selected artist and set the image on each button.

```
<div class="galleryimages">
    @if (SelectedArtist.HasImages)
    { 
        @foreach (Image image in SelectedArtist.Images)
        {  
           <ImageButton Image=image Parent=this></ImageButton>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Full source code and video:

Sample Project:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorImageGallery

Video
https://youtu.be/3xKXJQ4qThQ

Answer (score 1):

Blazor doesn’t support ~/. Simply remove the ~/ part from the src path value and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Read this[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and you'll understand how to solve your problem. Basically, you have to tell the framework to use the root directory, because by default it is searching for the file in the wrong place - http:///images/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dots instead of the pig tail, so it would be like this:

assuming that you put your images folder at the same level that the css folder is, otherwise you will have to insert the right route.