# Placing an icon inside an input HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place an icon inside an input in html. I have the code below but I can't get the image to show. I know the path to the image is correct so I can't find what is wrong here.
My objective is so that the icon appears on the left side of the input, "glued" to the left border.cand the placeholder appears after the icon.

```html
<input type="text" class="login" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
```

```css
.login {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    text-indent: 3rem;
}

#username {
    background-image: url(../wwwroot/images/login-user.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 2px 3px;
}
```

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser's Developer Tools - does the image request show up there? `wwwroot` looks suspicious to me, typically that is the document root and not something you'd expose on the web (so I'm guessing the url should be `/images/login-user.png`).

Comment: This is a blazor project, that is why the wwwroot folder exist. It is created in the template project and from what I learned I'm supposed to place the images used in the project in a image folder inside the wwwroot. I have used that path for other images in <img> tags and it works fine.

Comment: I've read the documentation here and it seems to agree with my point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/project-structure?view=aspnetcore-8.0

You are correct that you put static resources (e.g. images) in that folder, however my point is about *referencing* the resources there. The documentation says that that folder is the document root, hence your site starts from **inside** there.

It is possible you think the other <img> tags are fine because you opened the html files directly in your browser. This will not work as soon as you run your site in a server.

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66274925/314056 and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-8.0#code-try-5

Comment: Thank you for that information, I was unaware of that since I'm new to blazor.  If I maybe ask another question, the path i used, removing the ../wwwroot/, is the correct way to do it or is there a better way to give an url to an image? For example using an internet url of the image.

Comment: I don't know either, I've never used blazer. My suggestions are based on typical web dev experience. I'd advise to avoid opening your html directly in the browser - it will give you a false sense of security and it will not work in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that you know that your image path is correct, try once just an image-tag to see if it displays. Use an Image-Tag to cros-check this.

```
<img src="your path" alt="user" />
```

To solve your problem you can try something like this:

```js
const label = document.querySelector('label[for="login"]');
const input = document.querySelector('#login');

  // Hide the label when the input is clicked
  input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    label.style.display = 'none';
  });

  // Show the label when the input loses focus
  input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    // Check if the input is empty before showing the label
    if (input.value.trim() === '') {
      label.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
  });
```

```css
.login {
  position: realtive;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  width: 30%;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fake-placeholder{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px; /* move placeholder to the right when giving pixel sizes */
  color: grey;
}

.user-image {
  /* define image size here */
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label for="login" class="fake-placeholder">
  <img src="path-to-your-image" class="user-image" alt="user-image"/> Username
</label>
<input type="text" class="login" id="login" required>
```

``'

Comment: Thank you that worked. Not entirely what I was trying to do but it's a good work around!

Comment: Just keep in mind that what makes this work is that it moved the image path reference from the external css to your html file - I suspect in the end (when you run/build/publish your project) this won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is quiet simple to archive with some HTML/CSS

https://codepen.io/aeolous/pen/Exrpxwv

The HTML

```
<div class="form-element">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <div class="icon">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M3 4a2 2 0 00-2 2v1.161l8.441 4.221a1.25 1.25 0 001.118 0L19 7.162V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H3z" />
        <path d="M19 8.839l-7.77 3.885a2.75 2.75 0 01-2.46 0L1 8.839V14a2 2 0 002 2h14a2 2 0 002-2V8.839z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your@mail.com">
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.form-element{  
  max-width:250px; 
}
label {  
 display: block; 
}
svg { 
 width: 24px; 
 height: 24px; 
 color: #666; 
}

.input-wrapper {
 position: relative; 
 border-radius: 10px; 
}
.icon {
 display: flex; 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 padding-left: 12px; 
 align-items: center; 
 pointer-events: none; 
}

input {
 display: block; 
 padding: 8px;
 padding-left:44px;
 border-radius: 10px; 
 border-width: 0; 
 width: 100%; 
 color: #666; 
 line-height:1.5;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript nor SVG, all you need is some CSS. In the example below are two `<input>`s with the following CSS properties:

- `background` shorthand with values for:

  - `background-color` ex. `#000`
  - `background-image` ex. `url(https://i.ibb.co/PWwHp93/01.png)`
  - `background-position` ex. `left 2% top 0%`
  - `background-repeat` ex. `no-repeat`
- `background-size`

  - `contain` will resize the image edge to edge of it's parent element but maintain aspect ratio
  - `cover` will stretch the image edge to edge of it's parent element and will not maintain aspect ratio (unless it's parent element has the same aspect ratio)
- `::placeholder` a pseudo-element that can be styled

Akso, use `padding-left` of the `<input>` to push the cursor and placeholder away from the left positioned image.

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI";
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.25rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.15rem 0.5rem 0.25rem 2.25rem;
  font: inherit;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#username {
  width: 15rem;
  color: lime;
  background: #000 url(https://i.ibb.co/PWwHp93/01.png) left 2% top 0% no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#username::placeholder {
  color: rgba(86, 223, 76, 0.4);
}

#password {
  position: relative;
  width: 17.15rem;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000 url(https://i.ibb.co/0m6612N/static.gif);
  background-size: cover;
}

#password::placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 3.5rem);
  top: 0;
  width: 7rem;
  padding: 0.1rem 0 0.2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<input id="username" placeholder="Enter Username"><br>
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
```